# How do I set up the SignalR connection from the server side in .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an MVC application on .NET core 2.2. I want to send instant messages to users on a specified date. When I send it to the Hub with Javascript, it can be processed. But I cannot check the date from the database and trigger the Hub. I built the structure that will check every minute from DB from the address below. In this case, the connection state appears as a disconnect in the HubConnection section. I'm following the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2.

Hub Class Content:

```
public class TestHub: Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private HubConnection _connection;
    _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(myUrl).Build();
    _connection.StartAsync();
    //I will do database operations here
    _connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", "test"); //At this point, my connection state is in a disconnected state and my parameter cannot be passed to my "SendMessage" method on the hub.
}
```

Comment: So your service is opening a connection to a hub on itself? Why not just use Hangfire.io or another similair library to have tasks run a specific times?